# Storing Java Date object in REDIS

Tags: java, redis

I need to store a Java `Date` object in Redis. I'm using [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) as my Redis client. How do I store a Date object in Redis and retrieve it using Java? Everything I see uses String and Integer values. However, I don't understand enough about this world to do this with a `Date` object.

Comment: Can you convert the Date to A string and back again?

Answer (score 2):

How about converting the Date object to Epoch timestamp and converting it back to Date with any date format? This way you will not get into trouble with formatting errors..

```
//...convert date to epoch timestamp
Long time = new Date().getTime();

//...serialize it to a json object
job.addProperty("dateTime", time);

//...write it to redis
jedis.hset(KEY, field, job.toString());

//...retrieve the field and convert date with any format
model = gson.fromJson(jedis.hget(KEY, field), ModelClass.class);

//...print the date (suppose that the time field is of type Long)
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(format.format(model.getTime()));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using spring redis data and I map my entity as java.util.Date, but the redis repository itself convert to javax.sql.Date no idea why!

Answer (score -1):

You need to find a way to serialize the data and parse it later. Redis will only store strings, and Jedis doesn't provide serializers. [This conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jedis_redis/WEWpStWhS1Q) has more information about your use case.